# How to Import Image Sequence as Animation in Blender 3.6

Tags: animation, image, import, animation-nodes, image-sequence

Tried adding images as planes and using nodes but cannot add an image sequence as an animation. I have found instructions for older versions of Blender that explain how to add an image sequence as an animation and I have followed them but no success. The specific issue I am having is when I import the image sequence as a plane (via shift+A with the add on 'import image sequence as plane' enabled, or as file import) a small section of frames is imported and there lined up along the x axis. Some are stills and some animate for a few frames. Pictures below.

[image]

[image]

I have also tried different settings with offset planes and the align options such as changing it to focus on camera, main axis, etc. Here is a photo of one of the combinations I tried.

[image]

Sometimes the images would all be in the same space and not offset along the x axis but it would still only import image 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20, 30. I tried naming the files different but it still imported the exact same way. I have tried importing images as nodes (following instructions online) and my image will not show up on the plane. I made sure it was set to the correct amount of frames, auto refresh was turned on, but can only get the pink 'no information detected'.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or have any troubleshooting tips? I am aware that you can drag and drop an image sequence into the video editor but then I have no way to tell it to hold a frame or delete a frame. At the end of the day I just want to be able to add an image sequence and edit the length of frames being held. Thanks.

quick edit as I did not show in the original question but here is a photo to show that animate image sequence was selected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to import a video footage to blender is to convert the image sequence to a video first in a software like premiere pro or a free alternative software , nest the sequence , then import the video in the *Add images as planes* .

Comment: Hey thanks for answering however I'm hoping to be able to select individual frames and say hold for "n" frames. I'm doing 2d animation. Ive seen people do it on older versions of Blender where they select animate img sequence and it works perfect.